# tsconfig.json outDir in to parent

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to migrate my project to use ts.
Now I have two folders where I write my js files and I want tsc to compile the ts files in those folders without being inside them.

My current file tree is like this:

```
/
   Js /
      Files.js
   Mb /
      Js /
           Files.js
```

The file tree I want is:

```
/
   Js /
      Files.js
      Files.js.map
   Mb /
      Js /
         Files.js
         Files.js.map
   Ts /
      Js /
         Files.ts
      Mb /
         Js /
            Files.ts
Tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
    "CompilerOptions": {
        "Module": "commonjs",
        "RemoveComments": true,
        "PreserveConstEnums": true,
        "SourceMap": true,
        "OutDir": ".",
        "RootDir": "ts"
    }
}
```

But this does nothing, if I change "outDir": "../ build" does what I want but inside the build directory, but it does not suit me because I have to preserve the old architecture.

I can not have the .ts files in the same place as the .js files.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you might need more than what ts can give you to move files about in this way. have you tried grunt or gulp?

Comment: A configuration similar to what you wrote worked for me before. Now, it does not on the last version